# Change TextMeshProText to TextMeshProText UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I am searching how can I change my code so it will work my script.
I have wrote a script but but on my panel doesn't seem anything because I use TextMeshProText and I want to use TextMeshProText UI.
My line which I have this issue is this
I am using this library **using TMPro;**

`public TextMeshProText lT;`

I must replace on that code TextMeshProText with something reffer to TextMeshProText UI so it will seemed on the Panel..but I didn't find anything on this issue.Any idea how can I do this thing?

I have been trying alone to do this in unity with different ways but it needs to change this. If it is not TextMeshProTextUI at least Text(Legacy). I wasn't able to do this that's why I came here for help

Comment: You need to use TMP_Text

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution  it is **TextMeshProUGUI** .Let the answer for the other persons who search for it

Comment: You could even use `TMP_Text` class, which is base class of both `TextMeshPro` and `TextMeshProUGUI`